# Is it good practice to use sys.exit(0) at the end of a Python script?

Tags: shell, python-3.x

I'm learning to write Python 3 scripts to use in a shell. I have a textbook which seems to say that such a script should always use `sys.exit(0)` to end the script and return the code 0. Is that really necessary?

For example, suppose I run the following script with `python3 foo.py`:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('Hello world\n')
```

If I then do `echo $?` the response is '0'. So, the script did exit with code 0, and adding `sys.exit(0)` as the last line would have been redundant.

Should I leave it out, or is it still good practice?

Comment: Your book is bad, that's definitely not good practice. You usually want to use `sys.exit` either to conditionally end your script somewhere in the middle of it (when it would be complicated to simply change the execution flow) or to return a different exit code. As you've found out, it makes no sense to explicitly add it as the last line of a script, as the interpreter will always end with exit code 0 by itself if the code finished executing normally.

Comment: @l4mpi: you could post your comment as an answer. Do you see any reason, not to?

Comment: Thank you to @l4mpi, i am deleting my answer on grounds of possible violation of SO rules, to the OP i would say refer to the python docs, (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit). Further from my experience i would say it is a good habit to use in script.

Comment: @RicoRicochet: it is ok to cite the docs (especially only the relevant part) but you should indicate the quote clearly and provide the corresponding link.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I see no reason to post that as an answer - it's more of a comment, really. If you want to expand it to create an answer, feel free to do so.

Comment: yah, this part has been very clear to me now.. going through some docs of SO itself now.. :D

Comment: @RicoRicochet can you say more about why it's good practice?

Comment: @l4mpi Could your comment be an answer?

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to use `sys.exit(0)` at the end of your script if no problems have been found, and it is not good practice to do so.

If you need to exit early with an error, and you don't care about the exact non-zero exit code, you can use:

```
raise SystemExit('error message here')
```

The message will be printed and return code will be 1.  Otherwise, `print()` the message and use:

```
sys.exit(returncode)
```

to get a different returncode.

Comment: usually, `sys.exit('error message here')` is used instead of `raise SystemError('...')`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I use `raise SystemExit` myself, particularly if I have had no reason to `import sys`.